# What is the slowest diverging series whose sequence of terms diverge to infinity too?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am studying real analysis, and for some history as to how I got to this thinking, there was a result I had to prove that if $(a_n)$ converges to L, then $(s_n) =(\frac{\sum_{1}^{n}a_n}{n})$ too converges to L. It took a while, but I managed to prove it. But then it asked if there was a sequence $(a_n)$ where $a_n > 0$ that diverged and $(s_n)$ converged to $0$.

I have a theory that if $(a_n)$ is a limited sequence, then $(s_n)$ will converge to $\frac{\limsup a_n + \liminf a_n}{2}$, I didn't prove it, but that's not really where I want to get at.

So I started toying with $(a_n)$ that are not limited and positive. I know I should  have expected it to always be infinite, but still I went and tried stuff (I haven't attempted a proof yet, if anyone knows if that is true that would be some nice help to at least be sure that it is so), but toying with those got me curious about the question in the title.

I was trying to find some unlimited diverging positive sequence $(a_n)$ so that the numerator of $s_n$ was smaller than $n$ for all $n$ (or for all after a certain $N$), however I couldn't find a fixed formula for most candidates, like for example $(a_n) = n^{\frac{1}{2}}$, as $(a_n) = n$ didn't work, so nothing really helped much.

So I was wondering if there could even be an unlimited sequence like that whose sum went to infinity even slower than n could.

\\\

So... While I was writing this I had an idea, and made my mind against the previously mentioned theory I wrote. Would $(a_n)$ defined as $1/n$ while $n \neq k!$ and $k$ while $n = k!$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ work for an answer to the original question? It diverges and is positive, would $(s_n)$ converge to 0? Heck, it is even unlimited and seems like pretty slow, compared to other series of non limited terms.

Something like that would probably even answer the focus question of this thread, swapping $k!$ for even larger stuff, like $k^k$, and $1/n$ for $0$ would make some series that are even slower.

Comment: Try something like $(-1)^n$.

Comment: You did this, you noticed that, you have a theory... **What** is the question? (At one point you refer to the question in the title. If that's  what you want an answer to you need to restate it - I have no idea what the question in the  title means.)

Answer (score 1):

Idea: Find a sequence $x_n$ of $1$'s and $0$'s such that $(x_1+\cdots + x_n)/n \to 0.$ You do this by making the $1$'s very widely spaced. Now take any positive sequence $y_n\to 0.$ Consider the sequence $a_n = x_n+y_n.$